# FactoryGirl to create duplicate instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, factory

I'd like to test the uniqueness of entries on a `city` model.

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :country_code,
    message: "This city has already been added" }
end
```

I need to create a spec for testing this validation. My thinking is that the test will be along these lines:

```
my_city = FactoryGirl.create(:city)

context "when inserting" do
  it "cannot have the same name and country code" do
    expect{create :my_city}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::DuplicateRecord)
  end
end
```

However, I've been unable to figure out how to use FactoryGirl to create a duplicate instance of the `my_city` object. Simply using `create :my_city` as demonstrated in the above snippet results in:

```
ArgumentError: Factory not registered: my_city
```

**Edit**

This is what my `City` factory looks like:

```
# spec/factories/city_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :city do
    name { Faker::Address.city}
    country { CountryCodes.find(Faker::Address.country_code)}
    latitude { Faker::Number.decimal(2, 6)}
    longitude { Faker::Number.decimal(2, 6)}
    population { Faker::Number.number([3, 6, 7].sample) }
    timezone { Faker::Address.time_zone }
  end
end
```

So simple to run `create :city` twice, will result in two completely different cities being inserted. I need to test the same city, twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, testing uniqueness is pretty simple. Let the shoulda matchers do the work for you. Once you have a factory you can do this...

```
specify { 
  create :city; 
  is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:country_code) }
```

You must have at least one record created. Then the shoulda matcher will use that record, read its attributes, and make a duplicate to test your validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can test your validation like this:

```
RSpec.describe City do
  let(:city) { create :city }
  subject    { city }

  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:country_code) }
end
```

But first you need to build your factory (on a separate file )for City like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :city do
    sequence(:name) { |n| Faker::Lorem.word + "(#{n})" }
  end
end
```

Comment: See edit for my factory.
Your test, I think, is less direct than the one I've created. What is your test doing? It seems, at its crux, that `Faker` would create a different `word` every time `create` is called, so you're not really testing uniqueness at all, because the created city would be unique each call.

Comment: I misunderstood your spec!
Is there a way to keep it this simple without _without_ depending on `shoulda`? (I dislike adding more dependencies, but will if I must)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot put it in better words than the error tells you. You do not have a factory called `my_city` registered. If you would like to create a duplicate record, you simply call the `create` method twice and pass the duplicate attributes that you'd like to test. For example, you can test this in the following ways:

```
it "cannot have the same name and country code" do
  first_city = create :city
  duplicate_city = build(:city, name: first_city.name, country_code: first_city.country_code)
  expect(duplicate_city).not_to be_valid
end


it "cannot have the same name and country code" do
  attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for :city
  first_city = create :city, attrs
  duplicate_city = build(:city, attrs)
  expect(duplicate_city).not_to be_valid
end


it "cannot have the same name and country code" do
  first_city = create :city
  expect{create (:city, name: first_city.name, country_code: first_city.country_code)}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::DuplicateRecord)
end
```

Note that every time that you call the `create` method, you are creating a new record so the second time you call it there will already be an existing record in the database and the only attribute that will be different is the `id`. The exception to this is if you have declared a `sequence` in your factory or some other method call which will vary at time of test execution such as `Date.today`

Comment: See edit.
Also, you've used `create :my_city` which is the command that is causing me errors, thus my reason for writing this post. Perhaps you meant to write `create :city`.

Comment: You're right, it was a type. Updated my answer after reading your edit. TLDR; You can pass optional parameters to the build/create methods

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `shoulda-matchers` you could do this simply by using `FactoryGirl` to create the first city, then building another city with the same `name` and `country_code`. Finally, test the error messages it produces when validity is checked:

```
city = create(:city)
invalid_city = City.new(country_code: city.country_code, name: city.name)


expect(invalid_city).not_to be_valid
expect(invalid_city.errors.full_messages).to include "This city has already been added"
```